# Synchronization a function in multithreading C using a shared variable

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization

Trying to synchronize calling a function but in a high performance way, using just global variable

I'm trying to synchronize calling a function `foo` by this way:

```
bool global_var=0;
void* task(void*) {
    while(global_var);
    global_var=1;
    foo();
    global_var=0;
}
```

So, Can calling task() from more than a thread cause a data race or undefined behaviour?

Comment: `while(global_var);` (busy waiting) doesn't sound like "high performance".

Comment: probability of reading global_var as true: is so small. And when it happens `while` will not take more than 1ms to break

Comment: 1ms is *huge* for a computer executing instructions in fractions of nano seconds

Comment: Are you trying to invent [spinlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nothing guarantee you the boolean value isn't modified right after you exit the `while(global_var);`

From what I see, what you are trying to do it to ensure only one thread can run `foo()` at the same time. There are already objects specifically dedicated to this task, called *mutex*. Assuming you are using `pthread.h` :

```c
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;

int init_lock()
{
    return pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
}

void task()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    foo();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

This is the correct way of doing what I assume you are trying to do. Mutex are specifically designed to protect shared resources.

I recommend you read about mutex, semaphore and atomic variables.

Comment: If I had two threads and global vector class, each thread can push or read data of vector at any time, and the probability for data race to happen is so small.. So doesn't it so hard to use mutex for every time?

Comment: @AhmedKamal *the probability for data race to happen is so small*  How do you know what the probability is?  **Any** chance for a data race means you code is broken.  Nevermind your posted code also ignores aspects such as the visibility of changes to variables between threads - do some research on memory barriers as well as synchronization.

Comment: @AhmedKamal That's an uncommon approach in programming, but does exist in other engineering fields. I **strongly recommend against** this approach in a programming context, but it is theoretically valid. If you want to do it this way, you must first determine the MTTF (mean time to failure), the criticality of the failure, the recovering ability of the system, make an FTA (fault tree analysis), etc... You *can*, but there is a reason why nobody does it. If the MTTF of the entire system is higher than the acceptable failure rate, then yes, you can. But "small probability" is not precise enough.

Comment: Every time you leave a loophole like this, you make any subsequent debugging more difficult, more branches  more possibilities....  The CPU loop is a huge waste of cycles and memory bamdwidth:(

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your code may lead to a data race and undefined behavior. The variable, `global_var`, is not protected by any form of synchronization, such as locks or atomic operations, which means that multiple threads can potentially read and write to it simultaneously.